# Configure inline images upload path per content type

Tags: 8, media, uri, wysiwyg

There is a core feature that lets you configure where to save inline images uploaded using `CKEditor`:

[image]

Here you can specify the path where you want store inline images.

But this is global configuration, which works for all content types.

I want to have ability to control directory path per content type.

There is a module called [File (Field) Paths](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) which gives you ability to configure paths for only file fields under any content type but not for inline images.

Is there any module or a way to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Not directly. The only approach that I could think of right now is that you create a text format for each node type and then use a module like [Allowed Formats](http://drupal.org/project/allowed_formats) or [Better Formats](http://drupal.org/project/better_formats) to limit the allowed formats of each node type to that.

Maybe you can also alter the settings at runtime with some custom code based on the page that you're on right now, but I'm not sure.

Comment: `'#upload_location' => $image_upload['scheme'] . '://' . $image_upload['directory'],` -> you can't use tokens, otherwise tokens would've been an easy solution.

Comment: Somebody could write a D8 contributed module that `hook_form_alter()`s `EditorImageDialog`. That could then add token support.

Comment: Another possible approach is to upload files using a "File" field or install the Media module and upload files to your site's media library, and then embed those uploaded files using https://www.drupal.org/project/entity_embed.

Comment: Note that inline images are _intentionally_ simple like this. For now, the recommendation would be: create a D8 contrib module that alters `EditorImageDialog` that adds token support. If that sees enough usage, we can move that into core.

Comment: Finally, it'd be nice if you'd file this as a support request against https://www.drupal.org/project/issues/drupal?component=editor.module in the future. You'd have gotten a better reply there.

Comment: Thank you both, I'll try and let you know which approach worked best for me.

Comment: I discussed that with Wim and the token approach doesn't really work since you don't have the necessary context so you could actually have a token that is based on the node type. We should definitely support tokens there, but it will only allow you to do things like stored it based on the current date.

Comment: Yes that's right, I tried to implement this approach but I got stuck when I needed to get context of the node is being edited or created. I think if inline images had reference to $node where they were uploaded would be nice. 

But I'm not sure if it worked when user is creating new node.