# Ckeditor inline images path

Tags: files, wysiwyg

I am running a Drupal 9 site and I expect my users to upload a lot of files with the ckeditor functionality. All of those files will be
stored in a single folder.

I heard that this will cause performance issue once there are a lot of files. To avoid this, I would like to include a timestamp in to the path where to file will be stored, similar to what Drupal does to regular file uploads.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I found [this](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/193568/configure-inline-images-upload-path-per-content-type) question but it's 5 years old and there is no real answer.

Comment: *All of those files will be stored in a single folder. I heard that this will cause performance issue once there are a lot of files.* No, not really. Whatever you heard, it is totally outdated or doesn't apply to default Drupal.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil 

Answer (score 0):

Although stock Drupal may be OK with tons of files in a single directory, some Drupal hosts (e.g., Pantheon) have limits:

From [their docs](https://github.com/westonruter/pantheon-documentation/blob/master/source/docs/articles/sites/known-limitations.md):

> ### Highly Populated Directories
>
> If you have individual directories with tens of thousands of files
> (e.g. an image repository) it may be necessary to refactor this file
> structure to see good performance on Pantheon. The danger zone begins
> at around 50,000 files in a single directory, and performance drops
> off suddenly at over 100,000 files.
>
> Drupal itself is capable of managing uploaded content into different
> directories based on the date or user, which is preferable to dumping
> all uploads into a single place. Refactoring an existing large-scale
> site with this issue is usually simply a matter of re-arranging the
> files and then updating the files table in Drupal.

If you did need to implement this, you might look at what the [Filefield Paths module](https://www.drupal.org/project/filefield_paths) does.